# How many combinations of connected midpoints for a regular hexagon?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

Board game designer here looking for some help with tile design for a hex-tile based game. any help with my image example or wording to make this question more clear is greatly appreciated.

Consider the regular hexagon ABCDEF with midpoints 123456

[image]

How many possible groups are there to draw exactly three line segments that connect two midpoints. Example line segments 1-2, 3-4, 5-6 are one group and 1-3,2-4, 5-6 are a separate group. I want the set of all groups that meet the following conditions:
1: Each midpoint is connected by a line segment to exactly one other midpoint
2: Each set is not a rotation of another set (the part I'm really having difficulty with, and I am genuinely curious if this is something calculable.)

So, by the non-mathematical powers of brute force, I compiled the following list of groups:

```
(1-2, 3-4, 5-6),
(1-2, 3-5, 4-6),
(1-2, 3-6, 4-5),
(1-3, 2-4, 5-6),
(1-3, 2-5, 4-6),
(1-3, 2-6, 4-5),
(1-4, 2-3, 5-6),
(1-4, 2-5, 3-6),
(1-4, 2-6, 3-5),
(1-5, 2-3, 4-6),
(1-5, 2-4, 3-6),
(1-5, 2-6, 3-4),
(1-6, 2-3, 4-5),
(1-6, 2-4, 3-5),
(1-6, 2-5, 3-4)
```

After that I figured each new group would simply be a rotation of one of the existing groups turned 120 degrees.

So what I need is simply someone to check my work and see if I missed something, and help me root out duplicates. for example (1-2, 3-4, 5-6) and (1-6, 2-3, 4-5) are duplicates if one is rotated 120 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there are more than five up to rotation: three with an adjacent pair and two without

[image: hexagons]